# Silverlight Memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, memory

I'm designing a screen and I take data from a web service.

I was going to design the screen so that it called the web service everytime it needed data.

However I came to the realization that there are only 6 possible combinations returned from the web service.  So why don't I just keep the data in memory and use that instead.

Then I begin to wonder... how much memory is this really going to take up on the client?

Any idea how I can figure that out?

ie my array of custom objects is taking up 356k

Comment: so you already have the answer, or do you mean you could need to keep 6 different types of those 356 kb objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CLR Profiler to see how much memory a type and all the objects it references is taking up on the heap (Silverlight is CoreCLR):

[David Broman's CLR Profiling API Blog: CLRProfiler V4 Released](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032249/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released/)